# Adaptive Delayed chained payments

Tags: paypal

Please give me complete flow of Adaptive Delayed chained payments
1. account creation (Sandbox/Developer)
2. the code for sandbox endpoint
3. the classes will be used in the Adaptive Delayed chained payments
4. what will be happen after paykey returned ?
and if any other point i need to take care of.

Thanks for help.

---

The scenario is that customer pays amount to the store on the website via paypal and goes to the store to check the item and if found good he will receive his item and if found not good he/she will request for refund.
Now question is
{

i.  We are offering refund time is 7 days can we manage this time in paypal. That paypal gives refund time 60 days. Tell me if we will have to increase this by 60 days as paypal?

ii. Tell me if customer directly request for refund from paypal through site by using API?

iii.    If customer can request refund than is it possible that all the money received by both

primary and secondary receiver will be refunded at the same time to the buyer/sender?

iv. Similarly if store(secondary receiver) offers refund is that possible that secondary receivers amount and the stores amount will be refunded to the buyer at the same time.(current scenario in paypal,what I have seen that when secondary receiver clicks on issue refund the amount secondary receiver receives will be refunded to primary and then primary will be able to refund complete transaction to the sender)
}

Answer (score 0):

- Create an account at http://developer.paypal.com
- Within that account, create sandbox seller and buyer accounts for use with testing.
- Get your API credentials from the profile of the sandbox seller (app owner) account you're using.
- Build your API requests to PayPal (you didn't mention what programming language you're using..??).  Specifically, you'll make a call to the Pay API with the ActionType set to PAYPRIMARY.  This way only the primary receiver on the request will get the money at the start.  That response will include your PayKey, which you'll use to redirect the user to PayPal.  They complete payment, and the transaction is done.  When you're ready to submit payment to secondary receivers (the delayed payment(s)) you can make a call to ExecutePayment which triggers that.

The the basic idea, but the [PayPal Adaptive Payments documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) will cover all of this in much greater detail.

Comment: Thanks buddy. get your point and done with paypal payment, 

but how can now primary user will send money to secondary users? how much time he may delay this process?

I just read from paypal that delay will be for 90 Days can this delay be lesser or greater?

Comment: You could request it when you apply for the app and they may be able to adjust it for you, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. i found you really nice and helping.
i have moved further now 
i just made transaction with PAY_PRIMARY (Delayed chained payment)

the outcome is good and the transaction is successful.

But for further now i want the sender to refund the amount from my site. 
Is there any API that will allow sender to request for refund from the site ?

Comment: You can use the [Refund API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/) to refund Adaptive Payments transactions.